# Running Pleora EBus SDK samples all timeout

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gige-sdk

I'm currently trying to use the pleora sdk in order to connect to a FLIR AX5 thermal camera. I've tried to run all of the sample programs, found in ebus_sdk/share/sample. However, when I attempt to run them I am able to select the camera but all of the connections timeout.

But I am able to run the GEVPlayer without any issues.

I am running ubuntu 12.04

EBus_SDK Pleora_eBUS_SDK_2.2.3.2436_redhat-EL-5.4-64bit

Comment: I have no idea what the problem was I just ended up reinstalling the SDK and it started working.

Answer (score 2):

You should reach out to FLIR technical support for assistance.  They provide first-line support for Pleora's SDK when it is provided with FLIR cameras.

Also, FYI, version 2.2.3 of the SDK is quite old - somewhere between 1 and 2 years since release.  Not sure if it's relevant to your problem, but there have been a large number of improvements since then.  Version 3.1.7 is the latest.

John Phillips @ Pleora

Comment: Thanks, I knew the SDK was old, I'm not overly sure why my company is using it, it might be cheaper than the newer ones.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should make sure that the camera is not tied up elsewhere, ensure all connections to the camera via GEVPlayer are closed before starting your application.

Where I have seen the TIMEOUT exception, the main issues have been around the PVBuffer, If you are able to connect to the camera but are unable to stream, try negotiating the packet-size once more before Starting the Acquisition, this is something that GevPlayer does but the samples may not.

Assuming that your network card settings are correct (jumbo-frames enabled, 9k) etc the issue may be in timing, some cameras require longer to connect to than others and Gevplayer characteristics are not necessarily what you may see using the SDK. 
There should be a setting within the Communication Settings (cameraobject.GenLink) called AnswerTimeout. This can be increased, this will allow the camera more time between requests before it declares a timeout.

As mentioned above i would upgrade to the newest sdk 3.1.7, this should be free, as far as im aware pleroa licensing is not restrictive to a particular release version.

If you debug through your code and can find exactly where your code is crapping out i can provide more information.